# VB6 Code to move the printer head back to print position on next DOS print

Tags: printing, vb6, dos

In my Visual Basic 6.0 program, I used DOS print feature for high speed printing. 
The issue I am facing is that when print starts, the paper is not moving back to print start position of the print roller. Now the print starts from the last position from where the paper is teared off. It's very difficult and wasting time by pressing the printer's button to reset the paper back.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using these escape codes

```
ESC_RESET = Chr$(&H1B&) & Chr$(&H40&)
ESC_FORM_FEED = Chr$(&HC&)
```

Edit: Check [Part 3: Command Table](http://support.epson.ru/products/manuals/000352/part3.pdf) of Epson escape code. Search for Reverse paper feed (ESC j).

Comment: the code Chr$(&HC&) for Form Feed is working but the first one is not working. Thanks

Comment: actually I need to reverse form feed command